# How to spread or unclutter a network?

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I am trying to spread out or better visualize the network. The issue is the number of isolates I have seems to spread out the isolates and force the clusters into compact spaces that makes it hard to see patterns.

Does anyone have any guides to spread the clusters or better visualize the data. If you need, I can edit in the code.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to get a better layout. Both solutions require just a little experimentation to find good settings. First, since you do not provide any data, I will make an example that is vaguely like yours.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
g1 = erdos.renyi.game(100,0.35)
g2= erdos.renyi.game(10,0.35)
G = add_vertices(g1+g2, 50)
LO = layout_with_fr(G)
plot(G, layout=LO, vertex.size=5, vertex.label="")
```

[image: Poor layout]

**Solution #1** Adjust edge weights
If you don't need to use the edge weights for anything else,  you can just set the weights to something low so that there will not be such a strong attraction between connected points.  You may need to experiment to find a good value to use for the weights.

```
E(G)$weight = 0.01
LO = layout_with_fr(G)
plot(G, layout=LO, vertex.size=5, vertex.label="")
```

[image: Better layout through edge weights]

**Solution #2** Directly adjust the layout
You could also directly adjust the layout.

First, I identify which are the nodes that are too tightly clustered.

```
CM = components(G)$membership
table(CM)
```

For my graph, component 1 is the one that I want to expand. Next, I just shift the layout so that it is centered on the centroid of the first component. This does not change the graph; it just makes it easy for me to adjust the layout.

```
LO = layout_with_fr(G)
LO[,1] = LO[,1] - mean(LO[CM == 1,1])
LO[,2] = LO[,2] - mean(LO[CM == 1,2])
```

But now I can grow (or shrink) the first component by any given expansion factor.  I choose one (5.5) to take up most of the empty space.

```
LO[components(G)$membership == 1,] = LO[components(G)$membership == 1,] * 5.5
plot(G, layout=LO, vertex.size=5, vertex.label="")
```

[image: Directly adjusted layout]

Of course if you wanted to go back and adjust other components, you could do that too.

Comment: how do i attach data?

Comment: @EthanHunt Maybe the best way is to use `as_data_frame(g, what = "both")` to create a data frame, then convert that to text using `dput(GraphDF)` and paste the results into your question.