# How to incresase igraph distance for each edge in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a CSV file need to draw a graph.

[image: CSV file data]

The graph contains nodes and edges.

Therefore, I used the following code to do it.

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

#Loading Packages
library(igraph)
library(readr)
library(haven)

#import data
df = read.csv('../../Pre_Draw_Graph_for_R.csv', header = TRUE, encoding = 'UTF-8')

#Creating an iGraph Style Edge List
df_Edge_List <- df

#Creating Graph
df_graph = graph.data.frame(df_Edge_List, directed = TRUE)

#df Network: First Try
#Layout Options
set.seed(3500)
layout1 <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(df_graph)

#Node or vertex Options: Color
V(df_graph)$color <- "yellow"
V(df_graph)[degree(df_graph, mode = "in") > 500]$color <- "red"

#Edge Options: Size
E(df_graph)$color <- "grey"

#Plotting
plot(df_graph, vertex.label=NA)
#plot(df_graph)


end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

I can output the following result, but the result has some problems. It shows that every node is very crowded.

[image: My Graph]

[image]

I hope to increase the graph distance, but I used a lot of methods already. I cannot fix the problem. I hope to get the following result, but I cannot do it now. I want to make it clear to see the graph.

[image]

I used the following to show `dput` result.

`dput(df_graph, file = "G.R")`

Due to the data is too big, I used google link to share it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wdF8ZKFde8bDSrFrN9e9KfD3tm6dN_s0/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the answer to [How to spread or unclutter a network?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52348082/4752675)

Comment: I referenced your link, but it is not work

Comment: I used the method of link, it still very crowded.

Comment: Oh,  Then can you please provide your graph so that I can adjust?  Please type  `dput(df_graph)` and paste the output into your question so that I can work with your data.

Comment: Edited the question already

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way to a nice graph with a few simple changes. First,  change the vertex labeling to numbers as in your second graph. Also, use `layout_components` so that the components are separated from each other.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
LOC = layout_components(df_graph)
plot(df_graph, layout=LOC, vertex.label=1:vcount(df_graph))
```

[image: First plot of network]

This is OK, but the arrows are a mess. There are two reasons for that: the arrow heads are too big and most (all?) vertices have loops back to themselves. Let's remove the loops and reduce the size of the arrows.

[image: Second network plot]

This looks a lot more useable.  If you want anything nicer, you will need to start moving around badly placed vertices by hand. That is a lot more work,  but you get a nicer picture.

```
LOC[ 5,] = c(-1.5,-5)
LOC[ 9,] = c(-3,-2)
LOC[16,] = c(-3,14)
LOC[21,] = c(-3,18)
LOC[25,] = c(9,18)
LOC[29,] = c(-9,18)
LOC[35,] = c(-6,15)
LOC[30,] = c(-9,12)
LOC[31,] = c(-6,18)
LOC[37,] = c(1,14)
LOC[38,] = c(-9,15)
LOC[44,] = c(1,18)

plot(DFGS, layout=LOC, vertex.label=1:vcount(df_graph),
    edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

[image: Third and final plot - Adjusted by hand]

More could be done with the hand-editing, but I will leave that to you.